# IF/THEN BASH Best Practices

Tags: bash, if-statement, logic

I'm wondering if I've done this right.  I'm trying to learn BASH and really want to learn the "Best Practices" the first time, so I don't adopt the sloppy/easy way.

What I'm wondering, can I nest an IF/THEN statement like I've done below?  Why or why not?  Would the block below be served better by using an elif instead?

Lastly, I was hoping someone could shed some light for me on the use of "${foo}" and "$(bar)" ... curly braces or parenthesis?  I've (so far) used curly braces when I'm defining a variable "foo='bar'" is later called as "${foo} and parenthesis when I'm capturing a command "foo=$(find . -type f -name bar)" would be called as "$foo" ... or maybe I'm just way off and doing the same thing twice, I don't know ... I'd love to hear what you've all got to say! :D

```
# Downloading the script bundle
echo "Lets get the script bundle and get to work!"
wget http://place.to.get/att.tar

# Logic switch, checking if the TAR bundle exists. If it does
# verify the MD5 Checksum (to prevent corruption).
# If verfied, then un-tar the bundle in our working directory
# otherwise, exit with an error code, otherwise 
if [[ -f att.tar ]]
    then
        echo "Okay, we have the bundle, lets verify the checksum"
        sum=$(md5sum /root/att/att.tar | awk '{print $1}')
            if [[ $sum -eq "xxxxINSERT-CHECKSUM-HERExxxx" ]]
                then
                    tar -xvf att.tar
            else
                clear
                echo "Couldn't verify the MD5 Checksum, something went wrong" | tee /tmp/att.$time.log
                sleep 0.5
                exit 1;
            fi
    else
    clear
    echo "There was a problem getting the TAR bundle, exiting now ..." | tee /tmp/att.$time.log
    sleep 0.5
    exit 1;
fi
```

Comment: Curly-braces are for variable expansions (optional in many cases). Parentheses are for command substitution (and not optional if you need that functionality). `$foo` and `${foo}` are identical. You only need the braces when what follows the braces would be seen as part of the variable name. So `${foo}bar` is variable-foo then string-bar but `$foobar` is variable-foobar.

Comment: Run your code through http://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix the things it complains about. That snippet is pretty good on that front though. I wouldn't, personally, suggest using a different indent level for `then` and else` than you use for `if` and `fi` that's just going to be confusing I think. Personally I also use `if [ ...]; then` instead of putting then on its own line.

Comment: not a fan of your style of indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall comments

- Nothing wrong with nested "if's," but early exit would be clearer
- cut is cheaper than awk, but read is cheaper still
- Simple string equality tests are marginally cheaper with "[" rather than "[["
- Write error messages to STDERR
- Use read and < <() rather than $( | cut -f1 -d' ') because it avoids a pipe and second fork/exec
- Use functions

A simplified version

```
bail () {
    clear
    echo "${@}" | tee /tmp/att.${time}.log >&2
    exit 1
}

# Downloading the script bundle
echo "Lets get the script bundle and get to work!" >&2
wget http://place.to.get/att.tar || bail "There was a problem getting the TAR bundle, exiting now ..."

sum=''
read sum rest < <(md5sum /root/att/att.tar)

[ $sum == "xxxxINSERT-CHECKSUM-HERExxxx" ] || bail "Couldn't verify the MD5 Checksum, something went wrong"

tar -xvf att.tar || bail "Extract failed"
```

Comment: Using variables to store *the error messages* and *the `xxxxINSERT-CHECKSUM-HERExxxx`* might also help.

Comment: @RTLinuxSW what does "${@}" .... I tried to Google it, but no luck.  Also, I ran the code through shellcheck.net ... outstanding tool!  Several minor errors fixed, thanks!

Comment: "${@}" is explained in the BASH man page, section "Parameters," subsection "Special Parameters."  The importance of the double quotes is described in that paragraph.